# Apply functions to a set of data frames with 'multiprocessing'

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have three data frames, and I want to apply a function to each of them in parallel, using `multiprocessing`. (And keep their names.)

```
def loop(df):
    
    df = df.groupby('X').sum().reset_index()
    
    print('end of groupby')
    
    return

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=16)
df1, df2, df3 = pool.map(loop, [df1, df2, df3])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def loop(df):
    df = df.groupby('X').sum().reset_index()
    print('end of groupby')
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col': 1, 'X': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col': 1, 'X': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]})
    df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Col': 1, 'X': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]})
    with Pool(processes=3) as p:
        df1, df2, df3 = p.map(loop, [df1, df2, df3])
    print(df1)
    print(df2)
    print(df3)
```

Result:

```
end of groupby
end of groupby
end of groupby
   X  Col
0  1    3
1  2    2
   X  Col
0  1    2
1  2    2
2  3    1
   X  Col
0  1    1
1  2    3
2  3    1
```